# How to display login user name in New Item Form in Custom List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, javascript, list-form

I created one Custom Column name Employee Name it is Person/Group type, when user open New item current login user name show in this column

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom JavaScript in Script editor or Content editor web part on list form page.

**Example**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // get the title of current user  
        var currentUserName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
            fieldName: "Title",
            debug: false
        });
        //populate the field "Employee Name" with the current user  
        $('textarea[title^="Employee Name"]').val(currentUserName);
        $('input[title^="Employee Name"]').val(currentUserName);
    });
</script>
```

**Reference**: [Auto Populate Current User Login Name in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/auto-populate-current-user-login-name-in-sharepoint1)

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/helpdesk/support/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the current user details 
        var user = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();

        //Find the Specific People picker field "Employee Name" and set its value 
        $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
            peoplePickerDisplayName: "Employee Name",
            valueToSet: user,
            checkNames: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Reference**: [Set SharePoint People Picker Default Value to Current User](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/set-people-picker-default-value-to-current-user.html)

Comment: hi it will be work in NewForm.aspx ?

Comment: @ganeshsanap  the above code will work only if column type is single line text field or multiline text field

Comment: For people picker field, try solution given [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/set-people-picker-default-value-to-current-user.html). let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thank it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to set the people/group value with the current logged in user name

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetUserLogin() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : QuerySuccess,
  error : QueryError
});
}

function QuerySuccess(data, request){
  //removes the claims encoding
  var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];
  $("div[title='PeoplePickerColumnName']").val(loginName);
}

function QueryError(error) {
  alert(error);
}

GetUserLogin();

});
```